# React (Material UI) - Issues with form in component

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, components, material-ui

So, I'm trying to create a signup form for a web-app - but are running into a few issues.
I'm using hooks with a function to render signup page, which I'm routing to from the login page.

It works fine assuming I return the html directly from the return in the function (signup), but once the signup has been engaged, I wish swap the form for an acknowledge of it being send.

From what I can tell, people simply wrap each html in an arrow function and then toggles between using a bool or similar. But that's where the issues arrive.

**TLDR;**

One of the signup textfields autocompletes, fetching from an API. The API then saves the content in a hook variable (address). The second I update the address variable, the form seem to reset - cursor going to the first inputfield.

This only happens when I wrap the html in components, not if I insert all the html in the (signup) return.

I tried to clean it up a bit, but the code more or less look like this.
Any help or pointers would be great :)

```html
export default function SignUp(props)
{

    const [activeStep, setActiveStep] = React.useState(0);
    const [addresses, setAddresses] = React.useState([{ tekst: '' }]);

    const APICall = async (e) =>
    {
        e.preventDefault();

        // Fetchs JSON and set Addresses hook

    }

    const handleSubmit = props => form =>
    {
        form.preventDefault()
        setActiveStep(activeStep + 1);
    }

    const CreateAccount = (e) =>
    {
        return (
            <Container component="main" maxWidth="xs">
                <CssBaseline />
                <div className={classes.paper}>
                    <Avatar className={classes.avatar}>
                        <LockOutlinedIcon />
                    </Avatar>
                    <Typography component="h1" variant="h5">
                        Opret konto
        </Typography>
                    <form className={classes.form} noValidate
                        onSubmit={handleSubmit(props)}>
                        <Autocomplete
                            id="address"
                            options={addresses}
                            getOptionLabel={(option) => option.tekst}
                            style={{ width: 300 }}
                            renderInput={(params) =>
                                <TextField {...params} label="Combo box" variant="outlined" onChange={userTest} />
                            }
                        />
                        <Button
                            type="submit"
                            fullWidth
                            variant="contained"
                            color="primary"
                            className={classes.submit}
                        >
                            Sign Up
                        </Button>

                    </form>
                </div>
                <Box mt={5}>
                    <Copyright />
                </Box>
            </Container>
        );
    }

    const CreateAccountACK = () =>
    {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <Container component="main" maxWidth="xs">
                    <CssBaseline />
                    <div className={classes.paper}>
                        <Avatar className={classes.avatar}>
                            <LockOutlinedIcon />
                        </Avatar>
                        <Typography component="h1" variant="h5">
                            Nyt konto oprettet!
            </Typography>
                        <Button
                            type="button"
                            variant="contained"
                            color="primary"
                            className={classes.submit}
                            onClick={() => { props.history.push('/') }}
                        >
                            Ok
            </Button>

                    </div>
                    <Box mt={8}>
                        <Copyright />
                    </Box>
                </Container>
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }

    return (
        <div>
            {activeStep == 0 ? <CreateAccount /> : <CreateAccountACK />}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Hi, 
1. have you missed to include the `address` hook in the code snippet?

2. Random guess here  - when we wrap elements in components and when React conditionally renders it, it renders a new instance every time it is re-rendered so if the variable is not persistently stored in a state/variable, it will reset. But, would like to understand in detail what the problem is

Comment: Hi Rejo, thanks for the comment :). I misswrote, the hook is called addresses [addresses, setAddresses]. Is there a better alternative to how I'm doing things? Very new to react :)

Comment: Hi Ills, I can see that you are designing a step-through-step form (wizard like) in which I would recommend you to look into stepper https://material-ui.com/components/steppers/ which allows you to have distinct pages and steps for the process. Welcome to React, another side of awesomeness! :)

Comment: Once the selection is made on the components, you can store them in its state hooks to make it persistent throughout the process. ie, its good to have controlled components whose states are well known and interoperable. Refer https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components

Comment: Think think the issue is the autocomplete, which while the user is typing, fetches result from the API fuction - which then updates the addresses variable (which the autocomplete use). So when the user starts typing, the API starts fetching, and the component re-renders. I could try to store the state in the "CreateAccount" function instead, or perhaps extract it out into its own functional components and include the API?

Comment: Got it working by separating the functions out into their own functional component, including the variables/hooks/functions each needs. Seems to work, though I don't find a very elegant solutions :D Updated the post with code.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working by breaking each function into its own functional component, then render these from the main class (signup) using conditionals. Swapping between pages are handled by callback to "handlesubmit" in this function. Pass history as the final page routes back to main. Feel like this isn't the best way of doing this tho =D, but it avoids the issues with re-renders while typing.

So now the Signup just return ...

```html
export default function SignUp(props)
{
  const [activeStep, setActiveStep] = React.useState(0);

  const handleSubmit = props => form =>
  {
    form.preventDefault()
    console.log(form)
    setActiveStep(activeStep + 1);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {activeStep == 0 ? <CreateAccount handleSubmit={handleSubmit} /> : <CreateAccountACK handleSubmit={handleSubmit} history={props.history}/>}
    </div>
  )
}
```

And each function, hooks/variables exist in their own file/function.